# Jenkins Git plugin sometime prints the wrong branch name if the branch was created from other branch

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm using Git plugin for running Jenkins pipeline jobs. Sometime, After i create a new branch from an existing branch (Meaning both of the branches are pointing to the same commit), I get the wrong branch when i try to print the branch name.

For example: I create a new branch named `branch2` from other branch named `branch1`. When the job get triggered in Jenkins, Sometime it prints the original branch name (`branch1`). The issue get solved only when i commit any change to the new branch.

Here is an example of the pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Get Source Branch') {
            steps {
                    echo env.GIT_BRANCH
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows this issue? What could be the issue?
Please advise.

Comment: The operation of Jenkins is very mysterious. Git branches *do not* have a "branched from". Given a name like `branchX` there is no way to tell if it was created with `git checkout -b branchX`, or `git branch branchX <hash>`, or any other method of creating a branch name. It sounds like Jenkins is just plain *guessing:* when two or more branch names identify any one specific commit, it just picks one of the N branch names at random.